# Switching to 4K on external display shuts off the monitor

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display, ubuntu-gnome, 4k-monitor

Edit: **Upgrading kernel to 4.11-rc2 solved the issue.**

I have a brand new installation of Ubuntu Gnome on Lenovo Thinkpad L460. Can't seem to connect an external display to 4K mode via DP. FullHD and WQHD seem to work.

Someone suggested trying to install 4.4.8-040408-generic. Didn't work. Also installed intel-microcode proprietary drivers.

When I try to up the resolution to 4K from the displays screen,the monitor gets disabled. The following is printed to syslog:

```
Sep  7 10:46:10 juho-ThinkPad-L460 wpa_supplicant[2686]: wlp3s0: Failed to initiate sched scan
Sep  7 10:46:10 juho-ThinkPad-L460 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3011]: (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 3840x3240
Sep  7 10:46:10 juho-ThinkPad-L460 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3011]: (II) intel(0): switch to mode 3840x2160@60.0 on DP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
Sep  7 10:46:10 juho-ThinkPad-L460 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3011]: (EE) intel(0): failed to set mode: Numerical result out of range [34]
Sep  7 10:46:10 juho-ThinkPad-L460 gnome-session[3027]: Window manager warning: Configuring CRTC 63 with mode 226 (3840 x 2160 @ 59,996624) at position 0, 0 and transform 0 failed
Sep  7 10:46:10 juho-ThinkPad-L460 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3011]: (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 1, position (1920, 2160), rotation normal, reflection none
```

Edit: Here's the full journalctl output after attempting 4K in displays-config 
and pressing restore after.

```
syys 13 10:05:43 juho-ThinkPad-L460 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2928]: (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 5760x2160
syys 13 10:05:44 juho-ThinkPad-L460 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2928]: (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 1, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
syys 13 10:05:45 juho-ThinkPad-L460 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2928]: (II) intel(0): switch to mode 3840x2160@60.0 on DP1 using pipe 0, position (1920, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
syys 13 10:05:45 juho-ThinkPad-L460 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2928]: (EE) intel(0): failed to set mode: Numerical result out of range [34]
syys 13 10:05:45 juho-ThinkPad-L460 gnome-session[2944]: Window manager warning: Configuring CRTC 63 with mode 226 (3840 x 2160 @ 59,996624) at position 1920, 0 and transform 0 failed
syys 13 10:05:51 juho-ThinkPad-L460 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2928]: (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 4480x1440
syys 13 10:05:51 juho-ThinkPad-L460 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2928]: (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel: WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 2930 at /home/kernel/COD/linux/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_pm.c:3597 skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x1de/0x1f0 [i915]()
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel: WARN_ON(!wm_changed)
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel: Modules linked in:
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  snd_seq_dummy rfcomm bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic kvm arc4 binfmt_mis
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  mei snd_seq_device snd_timer snd soundcore mac_hid tpm_crb parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 e1000e ptp pps_core psmouse 
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel: CPU: 2 PID: 2930 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W       4.4.8-040408-generic #201604200335
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel: Hardware name: LENOVO 20FU002DMS/20FU002DMS, BIOS R08ET42W (1.16 ) 06/17/2016
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  0000000000000286 00000000592b92cf ffff88030df67810 ffffffff813cee93
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  ffff88030df67858 ffffffffc0273c70 ffff88030df67848 ffffffff8107fe12
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  ffff88030df6797c ffff88003541e000 ffff88003541f000 0000000000000000
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel: Call Trace:
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffff813cee93>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffff8107fe12>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffff8107feac>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffffc01add9e>] skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x1de/0x1f0 [i915]
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffffc01ae002>] skl_update_wm+0x252/0x7d0 [i915]
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffffc01f6ee4>] ? gen9_read32+0x124/0x2f0 [i915]
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffffc01b266e>] intel_update_watermarks+0x1e/0x30 [i915]
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffffc0217b77>] intel_atomic_commit+0x427/0x6f0 [i915]
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffffc007bb17>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffffc00ee5a6>] drm_atomic_helper_set_config+0x76/0xb0 [drm_kms_helper]
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffffc006ad22>] drm_mode_set_config_internal+0x62/0x100 [drm]
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffffc006f242>] drm_mode_setcrtc+0x3d2/0x4f0 [drm]
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffffc0060722>] drm_ioctl+0x152/0x540 [drm]
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffffc006ee70>] ? drm_mode_setplane+0x1b0/0x1b0 [drm]
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffff8121d108>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x298/0x480
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffff8108ceb1>] ? __set_task_blocked+0x41/0xa0
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffff8108f846>] ? __set_current_blocked+0x36/0x60
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffff8121d369>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffff8108fafe>] ? SyS_rt_sigprocmask+0x8e/0xc0
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel:  [<ffffffff81806276>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x75
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel: ---[ end trace 972d78447654bc07 ]---
syys 13 10:05:52 juho-ThinkPad-L460 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2928]: (II) intel(0): switch to mode 2560x1440@60.0 on DP1 using pipe 1, position (1920, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
syys 13 10:05:53 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel: snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: HDMI: ELD buf size is 0, force 128
syys 13 10:05:53 juho-ThinkPad-L460 kernel: snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 0
syys 13 10:05:53 juho-ThinkPad-L460 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2928]: (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 1920x1080
syys 13 10:05:53 juho-ThinkPad-L460 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2928]: (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 4480x1440
syys 13 10:05:53 juho-ThinkPad-L460 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2928]: (II) intel(0): switch to mode 2560x1440@60.0 on DP1 using pipe 0, position (1920, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
syys 13 10:05:53 juho-ThinkPad-L460 wpa_supplicant[2706]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
syys 13 10:05:53 juho-ThinkPad-L460 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2928]: (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 1, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
```

Comment: Does the external monitor support 4K?  *Numerical result out of range* looks like it does. What's the model name of the monitor? I don't understand why someone suggested to you to install an old kernel for wily from April, you should look for a more recent kernel in the kernel ppa like the latest 4.6, 4.7, 4.8 etc. … if you assume there is a driver issue and also look at Intel's site for graphics drivers, but read carefully what each download is for: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads

Comment: Yup, Samsung-U28E590D. Tried the Intel downloader instead of Ubuntu default downloader as well with no luck. Couldn't get 4.7 to boot. Might try 4.6 later, if no other suggestions surface. Not having high hopes of it being a kernel problem though.

Comment: please attach you /var/log/Xorg.0.log (check dates in log to be sure)

Comment: Instead of a newer kernel, you may want to try an older one. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1298528

Comment: @Juho 4.7.1 (.2/.3)  boots for me with Ubuntu-Unity 16.04 but not 14.04, what Ubuntu-Gnome version are you on? (your tags don't specify)

Comment: @Zacharee1: Yeah, tried 4.3 as well. No luck.

Comment: @Amias Sorry for the delay, couldn't get to the computer in question untill now. Seems like Gnome redirects X logs to journalctl. Added a full log of a a new try to the original post. That stack trace looks ominous.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you have become another casualty of the buggy i915 driver.

There are lots of options to try that are listed in this fedora bug report
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1188772

the main one being try to change the acceleration method to see which works best for your setup.

add this to your /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf and try each of the different accel methods by uncommenting one of them.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
#   Option      "AccelMethod"  "sna"
#   Option     "AccelMethod"   "uxa"
#   Option      "AccelMethod"  "glamor"
    Option      "TearFree"    "true"
EndSection
```

There are also a lot of boot options that might help , for a list of i915 boot options run the following command

```
modinfo i915 | grep '^parm:'
```

Comment: No luck. Every option resulted in both screens going dark either some time after entering login screen or after entering password.

Comment: and the boot params ? see the fedora thread for usefull combinations

Comment: Haven't had the time try them out yet. However I am pretty confident that this is on the right track. There either is a combination there that'll work with my hw, or not. If not, then I'll live with 2,5k and check out future updates. Either way, I think you deserve the bounty. Thanks :)

Comment: @Juho did you succeed with your T460 and can you then help me with http://askubuntu.com/questions/844877/which-laptop-for-ubuntu-16-04-with-4k-external-monitor ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check whether DisplayPort 1.2 is enabled on your display. Some UHD displays allow the DisplayPort version to be selected using the OSD. If your display defaults to 1.1, changing it to 1.2 might help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this isn't the cause. Was the first thing I checked.