# Which laptop for Ubuntu 16.04 with 4k external monitor?

Tags: laptop, monitor, external-monitor, displayport, 4k-monitor

I've been doing a lot of research but I can't seem to find an answer to this question.

A plethora of laptops exist that do work well with Ubuntu; that I know. Some even include a builtin 4k monitor that works fine.

What seems very hard to get reliable information about is:

**Which current (November 2016) portable laptop (max 14-inches, max 2.5kg/5.5lbs weight) can support an external 4k (3840x2160) displayport 1.2 monitor @60Hz, either directly or via an adapter/dock which is confirmed to work reliably?**

There seem to be an issue with modern laptops with USB-C-to-DP adapters or docks that aren't properly recognized by Ubuntu, and I'd like an hassle-free solution - in many forums about Dell XPS/Latitude/Inspiron I've seen people saying that sometimes they were able to work it out with custom kernels or arcane configurations, but I use my laptop for work and I don't want to waste too much time at configuring my laptop.

**PLEASE NOTE:** I expect exact make and models that **can be actually bought today in Europe**. Don't suggest me the specs, I already know what I'd like, but it seems that the requirements are conflicting enough that I cannot find a brand new laptop that has all of them at the same time.

Comment: @PatrickNegus please don't mingle "hardware capabilities" with "works on Ubuntu". Can you provide a single example of a 13-inch or 14-inch laptop currently on sale (that's important! some older models worked, but they're being no longer sold!) that is got a DP port and works with ubuntu? 

While USB-C is ok ON PAPER, many USB-C to DP adapters or docks don't work or work unreliably on Ubuntu; you can find many reports of this behaviour, especially with modern Dell XPS systems.

Comment: I'll add: HP Elitebooks are currently VERY scarce here in Italy. I think they're updating them to Kaby Lake like probooks, and the current generation is very hard to find.

Comment: I'd vote to close this question as too broad or off topic if question with open bounties could be closed.

Comment: @DavidFoerster could you elaborate why? I tried to be as specific as possible. I did my research online, finding this information nowhere. And this not a request for a shopping recommendation based on opinions - I'm asking for FACTS about a very specific feature.

If you think I should ask this somewhere else to stay on topic, just tell me, I'll delete and move the question.

Comment: See [Why don't we allow shopping recommendations?](/q/8922/175814). There's a whole StackExchange site dedicated to hardware shopping recommendations: [HardwareRecs.SE].

Comment: @DavidFoerster your first link points to the wrong thing, but I found http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8922/why-dont-we-allow-shopping-recommendations which I suppose is the correct one. Exactly my point. I'm not asking for a subjective "best hardware for the money I have" - I'm asking "has anybody had success at X on Ubuntu?". It's a yes/no answer with little to no subjectivity left - as a proof, I got zero valid answers in many days, even with a bounty. I'll rephrase things a bit, by the way.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's the link I mean. If you look at [the answer](//meta.askubuntu.com/a/8923/175814) though you'll see that it covers the issue more broadly and that your question still falls under its description and reasoning.

Comment: This question is about hardware recommendation. It should be closed.

Comment: Great, let's close it. Even though it would be very useful, it's perfectly on topic - it's about using Ubuntu, after all, isn't it? - and there's no good answer on the whole internet. Welcome the SO thoughtpolice to askubuntu: https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

Comment: I cannot delete it since it's got an open bounty. I'll delete it as soon as the bounty period is over.